# IOS screen orientation is messed up after taking a picture using Html file input

Tags: ios, html, orientation-changes

In our web application we have a `<input type="file">` and in IOS when user presses that, s/he is sent to camera and the taken picture is posted to our server.

If application is added to home screen and run from there, screen orientation is messed up when following is done:

1. Hold the device in portrait mode
2. Press on file upload input --> you will be sent to camera app
3. Change orientation of the device
4. Take the picture

--> Orientation is switched back to portrait in web app

Has anyone experienced this problem?